# c# переопределение ToString() для коллекции

Tags: c#, коллекции, переопределение

Как можно переопределить метод ToString() для коллекции?

```
List<Place> spisok = new List<Place>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
     spisok.Add(new Place(PlaceStatus.Free));
```

Я хочу при вызове `spisok.ToString()` я получал String формата 0,0,0,0 (т.е. элементы через запятую)

Или для такой коллекции аналогично

```
var spisok = new Place[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
     spisok[i] = new Place(PlaceStatus.Free));
```

Ниже код используемых элементов. В классе попытался перегрузить метод ToString(), он выдает числовые значения, когда объект 1. Но в случае с массивом, это текст - запись о классе

```
    public enum PlaceStatus
    {
        Free,
        Booked,
        Paid,
        Confirmed
    }
    public class Place
    {
        public PlaceStatus Status { get; set; }

        public Place(PlaceStatus status)
        {
            Status = status;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ((int)Status).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте статический класс-helper. Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public static class PlaceCollectionHelper
{
    public static string ToString(this IEnumerable<Place> Collection, string Separator)
    {
        return string.Join(Separator, Collection);
    }
}
```

И далее используйте в своём коде:

```
string spisokStr = spisok.ToString(",");
```

---

**UPD:**
Предыдущий вариант является расширением, так как явно переопределить ToString() у существующей коллекции нельзя. Однако если Вам необходимо, чтобы сторонние методы могли вызывать нужное Вам преобразование Вашей коллекции в строку, придется создавать новый тип, который будет наследоваться от типа нужной Вам коллекции. Здесь есть 2 пути. Давайте рассмотрим их.

---

0) Самым лаконичным решением будет то, которое представлено в соседнем ответе:

```
public class PlaceCollection : List<Place>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", this);
    }
    public string ToString(string Separator)
    {
        return string.Join(Separator, this);
    }
}
```

Вы просто создаете класс, который наследуется от листа с нужным Вам типом, где и переопределяете ToString() нужным Вам образом. Как Вы понимаете, работает эта конструкция точно так же, как и обычный лист:

```
PlaceCollection collection = new PlaceCollection { new Place(PlaceStatus.Free), new Place(PlaceStatus.Booked) };
collection.Add(new Place(PlaceStatus.Paid));
```

Однако теперь, если Вы вызовете, скажем, `Console.WriteLine`, которая при передачи в нее объекта автоматически вызывает у него ToString(), то получите уже:

```
Console.WriteLine(collection);
// 0, 1, 2
```

---

1) Предыдущий вариант подойдет Вам лишь в том случае, если в качестве коллекции Вы используете List. Однако в Вашем втором примере ясно видно, что Вы так же используете и массив для своих целей. Так что в решении Вашей задаче нам поможет наследование от generic-интерфейса `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class PlaceCollection : IEnumerable<Place>
{
    #region Var
    private IEnumerable<Place> Collection { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Init
    public PlaceCollection(IEnumerable<Place> Collection)
    {
        this.Collection = Collection;
    }

    public static implicit operator PlaceCollection(List<Place> Collection)
    {
        return new PlaceCollection(Collection);
    }
    public static implicit operator PlaceCollection(Place[] Collection)
    {
        return new PlaceCollection(Collection);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    public IEnumerator<Place> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", Collection);
    }
    public string ToString(string Separator)
    {
        return string.Join(Separator, Collection);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Доступ к элементам можно производить при помощи `Linq`, либо же дописать свои индексаторы. В данном классе реализовано неявное приведение, так что Вы вполне можете сделать так:

```
Place[] placeArray = new Place[] { new Place(PlaceStatus.Free), new Place(PlaceStatus.Booked) };
PlaceCollection collection = placeArray;
```

Или так:

```
List<Place> placeList = new List<Place> { new Place(PlaceStatus.Free), new Place(PlaceStatus.Booked) };
PlaceCollection collection = placeList;
```

Однако результат все равно будет один:

```
Console.WriteLine(collection);
// 0, 1
```

И так как наследовались мы от `IEnumerable<Place>`, то Вам доступно получение энумератора:

```
foreach (Place p in collection)
    Console.WriteLine(p);
// 0
// 1
```

---

Выбирайте наиболее удобный Вам метод и удачи в Ваших решениях)

Comment: Но это же не переопределение (override), это просто метод расширения и всякие `Console.WriteLine(spisokStr)` пользоваться им не будут!

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вы ведь знаете, что фактическое переопределение для сего невозможно) Нужно как в примере ниже создавать свой тип для сего)

Comment: Я-то знаю, но это должен знать и автор вопроса, не так ли?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вы правы) Дополню ответ, когда вернусь

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MyTypeList : List<MyClass>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```